# Retrieve many-to-many ids as array

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables, `Foos`, `Bars`, and a many-to-many table `FoosBars`. Each table have their own auto-incrementing `INT` as primary key, and `FoosBars` has two columns: `FooId`(foreign key to `Foos.Id`) and `BarsId`(foreign key to `Bars.Id`). In my application (C#) I want to populate my `Foo`-objects with the columns from the `Foos` table, plus an array/list of associated BarIds. For now, i have queried the database twice: once to retrieve all the Foos I want(`select * from Foos where X`), and then again to retrieve the FoosBars (`select * from FoosBars inner join Foos on Foos.Id=FoosId where X`), and then populate each `Foo`-object's BarIds in my application.

This however requires me to store the FoosBars objects temporarily in my application, and I need to have a class to represent the FoosBars, which I would like to avoid. Is there a way to retrieve the correct FoosBars as an array?

I had something like this in mind:

```
Select *, (select BarsId
  from [this Foo]
  inner join FoosBars on Foos.Id=FoosId
) as BarIds
From Foos
Where X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subquery in the select **must return one value** so the provided example is invalid. Moreover when you execute a query you should expect a result set (i.e collection of rows), not an array, or any other type.

Nothing prevents you from using it in the most simple manner:

```
select *
from [Foos]
inner join FoosBars on Foos.Id=FoosId
```

You might need to consider changing the way you populate your objects based on this result set.

For each row:

- If you encounter new Foo -> Create it, otherwise ignore it
- Add a FoosBars item to an existing Foo

Comment: I am aware that the subquery in the select clause must return one value, so I was wondering if there was a way to return a value of type int array

Comment: As I stated, it's not possible

Comment: Okay,thanks for your informative answer with suggested solution :-)

Comment: Sure.. and your need makes sense. In general, this task is called [Object relation mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). In relational databases it often take some effort to achieve that. With document stores it gets a bit more easy